# E3D V6 hotend gets jammed very frequently

Tags: e3d-v6, filament-jam

In the past couple of weeks, my V6 hotend gets jammed very frequently. The nozzle is 0.4 mm and the printer is a D-Bot.

Here are some of the things I have tried so far,

1. Switched between the original and a clone and both get jammed.
2. Tried different heat breaks - the one where the Bowden PTFE tube goes all the way to the nozzle, the one where its an all metal one and the one that has a PTFE liner inside it.
3. Checked and re-calibrated the E steps and the PID tuning for the nozzle.
4. Used different filaments (PLA).
5. Tightened the nozzle against the heat break every time
6. Tried different printing speeds and also calibrated the extrusion multiplier.
7. Tried different retraction speeds and lengths.
8. Ensured that the heat sink is adequately cooled.

What could I be missing?

Comment: Is it a genune or a knockoff v6? what are your settings? What material?

Comment: Make sure the nozzle body isn't actually touching the heater block. There should be a small gap when it's fully tightened. If there isn't you will need to [adjust the hot end/heat break](https://www.matterhackers.com/articles/how-to-assemble-an-e3d-v6-all-metal-hotend).

Comment: @Trish As stated above, I've tried both the genuine and the clone and I'm facing problems with both. Material is PLA, being printed at 200 deg C, 60 deg C heatbed, 60mm/s print speed. Retraction is set at 2mm and retraction speed is 50mm/s.

Comment: @BobT The nozzle body is not touching the heater block. I usually insert the heat break first to ensure that the exposed break is right between the heat sink and the block and then add the nozzle.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having he same problem.

Comment: @Biclops not really. I finally gave up and bought a whole new 3D printer. I was done with DIY options.